# What is a "span" and when should I use one?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-faq, cpp-core-guidelines, std-span

Recently I've gotten suggestions to use `span<T>`'s in my code, or have seen some answers here on the site which use `span`'s - supposedly some kind of container. But - I can't find anything like that in the C++17 standard library.

So what is this mysterious `span<T>`, and why (or when) is it a good idea to use it?

Comment: @jww: span's are quite usable with C++11... as `gsl::span` rather than `std::span`. See also my answer below.

Comment: Also documented on cppreference.com: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span

Comment: @KeithThompson: Not in 2017 it wasn't...

Comment: @jww All compilers support std::span<> now in C++20 mode. And span is available from many 3rd party libs. You were right - it was years: 2 years to be precise.

Answer (score 516, accepted):

### What is it?

A `span<T>` is:

- A very lightweight abstraction of a contiguous sequence of values of type `T` somewhere in memory.
- Basically a `struct { T * ptr; std::size_t length; }` with a bunch of convenience methods.
- A non-owning type (i.e. a ["reference-type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827592/what-is-definition-of-reference-type) rather than a "value type"): It never allocates nor deallocates anything and does not keep smart pointers alive.

It was formerly known as an [`array_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34832090/1593077) and even earlier as [`array_ref`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html).

### When should I use it?

First, when *not* to use spans:

- Don't use a span in code that could just take any pair of start & end iterators (like `std::sort`, `std::find_if`, `std::copy` and other  templated functions from `<algorithm>`), and also not in code that takes an arbitrary range (see [The C++20 ranges library for information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) about those). A span has stricter requirements than a pair of iterators or a range: element contiguity and presence of the elements in memory.
- Don't use a span if you have a standard library container (or a Boost container etc.) which you know is the right fit for your code. spans are not intended to supplant existing containers.

Now for when to actually use a span:

> Use `span<T>` (respectively, `span<const T>`) instead of a free-standing `T*` (respectively `const T*`) when the allocated length or size also matter. So, replace functions like:
>
> ```
> void read_into(int* buffer, size_t buffer_size);
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> void read_into(span<int> buffer);
> ```

### Why should I use it? Why is it a good thing?

Oh, spans are awesome! Using a span...

- means that you can work with that pointer+length / start+end pointer combination like you would with a fancy, pimped-out standard library container, e.g.:

  - `for (auto& x : my_span) { /* do stuff */ }`
  - `std::find_if(my_span.cbegin(), my_span.cend(), some_predicate);`
  - `std::ranges::find_if(my_span, some_predicate);` (in C++20)

  ... but with absolutely none of the overhead most container classes incur.
- lets the compiler do more work for you sometimes. For example, this:

  ```
  int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  read_into(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  ```

  becomes this:

  ```
  int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  read_into(buffer);
  ```

  ... which will do what you would want it to do. See also [Guideline P.5](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p5-prefer-compile-time-checking-to-run-time-checking).
- is the reasonable alternative to passing `const vector<T>&` to functions when you expect your data to be contiguous in memory. No more getting scolded by high-and-mighty C++ gurus!
- facilitates static analysis, so the compiler might be able to help you catch silly bugs.
- allows for debug-compilation instrumentation for runtime bounds-checking (i.e. `span`'s methods will have some bounds-checking code within `#ifndef NDEBUG` ... `#endif`)
- indicates that your code (that's using the span) doesn't own the pointed-to memory.

There's even more motivation for using `span`s, which you could find in the [C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) - but you catch the drift.

### But is it in the standard library?

**edit:** Yes, [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) was added to C++ with the C++20 version of the language!

Why only in C++20? Well, While the idea is not new - its current form was conceived in conjunction with the [C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) project, which only started taking shape in 2015. So it took a while.

### So how do I use it if I'm writing C++17 or earlier?

It's part of the [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p3-express-intent)'s Support Library (GSL). Implementations:

- Microsoft / Neil Macintosh's [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) contains a standalone implementation: [`gsl/span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span)
- [GSL-Lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite) is a single-header implementation of the whole GSL (it's not that big, don't worry), including `span<T>`.

The GSL implementation does generally assume a platform that implements C++14 support [[12](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/7d78b743e43ecba06ca47426d03d9d16076dec16/README.md#L9)]. These alternative single-header implementations do not depend on GSL facilities:

- [`martinmoene/span-lite`](https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite) requires C++98 or later
- [`tcbrindle/span`](https://github.com/tcbrindle/span) requires C++11 or later

Note that these different span implementations have some differences in what methods/support functions they come with; and they may also differ somewhat from the version adopted into the standard library in C++20.

---

**Further reading:** You can find all the details and design considerations in the final official proposal before C++17, P0122R7: [span: bounds-safe views for sequences of objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf) by Neal Macintosh and Stephan J. Lavavej. It's a bit long though. Also, in C++20, the span comparison semantics changed (following [this short paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1085r2.md) by Tony van Eerd).

Comment: Wouldn't `read_into(int* from, int* to)` be way more in line with the usual (iterator based) approach of the standard library?

Comment: @DanielJour: I wanted a minimalistic example. Both your and my variant of the functions would probably not be something you would actually put in a library anyway. Also, note that with your variant, it's not possible to know how much you need to read, so maybe you mean `read_into(int* from, int* to, size_t n)`? That's mentioned in the Core Guidelines document as a "bad example" actually.

Comment: @einpoklum oh, no, that's not what I meant. Different take: `read_into(int* begin, int* end)`

Comment: @DanielJour: Ah well, the thing is, with a `span<T>`, you don't know/don't care whether internally it has `int* begin; size_t length` or `int* begin; int* end;` So I don't think it matters all that much.

Comment: It would make more sense to standardize a general range (supporting iterator+sentinel and iterator+length, maybe even iterator+sentinel+length) and make span a simple typedef. Because, you know, that's more generic.

Comment: Pity that they didn't standardize the representation, so it could be used for interop between different languages.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ranges are coming to C++, but the current proposal (by Eric Niebler) requires support for Concepts. So not before C++20.

Comment: Can you explain how span can know the size of an array while it is constructed just by the array pointer alone ? Is it due to span can read the bytes next to the pointer to get the size info (I guess these bytes are also allocated by `new` or `malloc`, so they can correctly `delete` it later)? 
I can not find any article about this, and hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @HảiPhạmLê: Arrays don't immediately decay into pointers. try doing `std::cout << sizeof(buffer) << '\n'` and you'll see you get 100 sizeof(int)'s.

Comment: @einpoklum : I see, yes, you're right. Is it true that compiler can tell the size of buffer since it's known at compile time ? `sizeof` is also compile time function. But, what about memory allocated dynamically by `new` or `malloc`? Can `span` work with them ?

Comment: @HảiPhạmLê: It can tell the size of the buffer because buffer is defined as a sized array. That has nothing to do with compile-time vs. run-time. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) here on SO.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages compared to [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @Jim `std::array` is a container, it owns the values. `span` is non-owning

Comment: @Jim: `std::array` is a completely different beast. Its length is fixed at compile-time and it's a value-type rather than a reference-type, as Caleth explained.

Comment: Example around `read_into(buffer);` is the key issue I am having here.  Native array reference, very successfully kills the 'span' idea in that scenario.  It is "fundamental vocabulary type" in the same way std::span might be. I "need" this clearly mentioned in 'span' jubilation's.

Comment: ards set example

Comment: Tristan Brindle's [implementation of `span`](https://github.com/tcbrindle/span) has the benefit to be only a single header-file with few lines of code, supports *C++11 or later* and has no dependencies to other GSL facilities.

Comment: @user5534993: How is this comment improving on what I've already written?

Comment: The biggest advantage over an STL container that could serve as a quasi-`span` (like `array` or `vector`), @Jim, is that you don't need to awkwardly turn it into a reference type by storing a pile of pointers or `reference_wrapper`s to the data you'd want to view.

Comment: So basically, `span` is like `string_view`, but works with any type, not only with `char`, right?

Comment: @Ruslan: There are similarities between them - but they are not the same. There are significant differences, at least in terms of their available methods.

Comment: "*a bunch of convenience methods*" is a rather disparaging term for **a standard collection interface**, don't you think?

Comment: @einpoklum, please update the answer to explain in detail how `span` differs from `std::array`, and which one is better for what, why.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: I will not. There is no reason to focus on `std::array` here, as opposed to any other specific container. Also, if you know `std::array` at all, then the answer does explain how they differ. IMHO.

Comment: It's not clear enough in a single pass to someone who's never heard of a span before. This is sufficient: please replace your 2nd bullet with this: "- Basically a **single** `struct { T * ptr; std::size_t length; }` with a bunch of convenience methods. (Notice this is distinctly different from `std::array<>` because a `span` enables convenience accessor methods comparable to `std::array` via a _pointer to type `T`_ and length of type `T`, whereas `std::array` is an actual container which holds one or more _values_ of type `T`.) ". Done. That's all I'm asking for. This helps so much.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: There is no reason to focus on std::array rather than, say `std::vector`.

Comment: _"reasonable alternative to passing const vector<T>& to functions when you expect your data to be contiguous in memory"_. Could somebody expand? Aren't vectors contiguous in memory?

Comment: @luizfls: They are. But if that's what your function needs - don't insist on the input being an `std::vector` - any contiguous sequence of memory will do, and the span is just the container to represent it.

Comment: first you say to not use it with `std::find_if` and then you use it yourself... I feel like a different wording is needed

Comment: Specifically about `cstring_span<>`, this specific span doesn't store any character data, correct? So hypothetically, if I had a `cstring_span<>` that was, e.g., allocated from `std::string::c_str()`, it would also have the same lifetime that the `char*` from `c_str` would have, correct? What value does a `cstring_span` add over just working with the `char*` or `std::string`?

Comment: @jrh: Thanks for noticing the typo. Anyway - I don't know about a `cstring_span`; that's not in the standard library and not in my answer. But generally - spans don't store any data. And, yes, its lifetime is the same as the pointer. "What value does it add" <- It has the length, on the one hand, and it's a cheap simple structure which doesn't own any memory, on the other.

Comment: @einpoklum ah, I see, I wasn't aware that it was non-standard. I noticed it was in an old version of GSL, I wasn't sure where it came from. Thanks!

Comment: “Don’t use it in code that could just take any pair of start & end iterators” ― Why? Isn’t `std::span` meant to get rid of pairs?

Comment: @КонстантинВан: No... pair-of-iterators is much more general. For example: `std::list`'s beginning and end are two iterators, but the elements are not consecutive in memory, so it doesn't fit a span.

Comment: @einpoklum: While “Don’t use it in code that could just take any pair of start & end iterators” isn't wrong, it's also not completely correct unless it points the reader to Ranges (`<ranges>` header).

Comment: @BenVoigt: The answer predates C++20, when there was no such thing. I suppose I might want to rethink that point.

Comment: @einpoklum: I considered that possibility but the answer mentions C++20 quite a few times.  It's not like Ranges are proposed more recently than span either.

Comment: @einpoklum ***Don't use a span in code that could just take any pair of start & end iterators (like std::sort, std::find_if, std::copy and other templated functions from <algorithm>)*** Why?Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: Can I summarize that std::span is the "dynamic" version of std::array ?

Comment: @walkerlala: No, because it is absolutely not that. `std::array` owns the data; `std::span` does not.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike  Yes you are right with that. I think std::span means "array ref", and should be renamed to ArrayRef, as LLVM does  https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html

Comment: @walkerlala: If you'll read the first section of my answer, you'll note it used to be named that.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike Do you know why the name was dropped ?

Comment: @walkerlala: No, you'll have to ask committee members. I suspect it may be due to a desire to avoid an overly close association with `std::array` but who knows.

Answer (score 58):

A `span<T>` is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct span
{
    T * ptr_to_array;   // pointer to a contiguous C-style array of data
                        // (which memory is NOT allocated nor deallocated 
                        // nor in any way managed by the span)
    std::size_t length; // number of elements of type `T` in the array

    // Plus a bunch of constructors and convenience accessor methods here
}
```

It is a light-weight wrapper around a C-style array, preferred by C++ developers whenever they are using C libraries and want to wrap them with a C++-style data container for "type safety" and "C++-ishness" and "feelgoodery". :)

*Note: I call the struct container defined above, known as a span, a "light-weight wrapper around a C-style array" because it points to a contiguous piece of memory, such as a C-style array, and wraps it with accessor methods and the array's size. This is what I mean by "light-weight wrapper": it is a wrapper around a pointer and a length variable, plus functions.*

*Unlike a `std::vector<>` and other C++ standard containers, however, which may also just have fixed class sizes and contain pointers which point to their storage memory, a span does not own the memory it points to, and will never delete it nor resize it nor allocate new memory automatically. Again, a container like a vector owns the memory it points to, and will manage (allocate, reallocate, etc.) it, but a span does not own the memory it points to, and therefore will not manage it.*

---

### Going further:

@einpoklum does a pretty good job of introducing what a `span` is [in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723820/4561887). However, *even after reading his answer,* it is easy for someone new to spans to still have a sequence of stream-of-thought questions which aren't fully answered, such as the following:

1. How is a `span` different from a C array? Why not just use one of those? It seems like it's just one of those with the size known as well...
2. Wait, that sounds like a `std::array`, how is a `span` different from that?
3. Oh, that reminds me, isn't a `std::vector` like a `std::array` too?
4. I'm so confused. :( What's a `span`?

So, here's some additional clarity on that:

DIRECT QUOTE OF HIS ANSWER--WITH ***MY ADDITIONS* and parenthetical comments IN BOLD** and *my emphasis in italics*:

> ### What is it?

> A `span<T>` is:

> - A very lightweight abstraction of a *contiguous sequence of values* of type `T` somewhere in memory.
> - Basically a **single** struct `{ T * ptr; std::size_t length; }` with a bunch of convenience methods. **(Notice this is distinctly different from `std::array<>` because a `span` enables convenience accessor methods, comparable to `std::array`, via a *pointer to type `T`* and length (number of elements) of type `T`, whereas `std::array` is an actual container which holds one or more *values* of type `T`.)**
> - A *non-owning type* (i.e. a ["reference-type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832090/whats-the-difference-between-span-and-array-view-in-the-gsl-library) rather than a "value type"): It *never allocates nor deallocates anything* and does not keep smart pointers alive.

> It was formerly known as an [`array_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832090/whats-the-difference-between-span-and-array-view-in-the-gsl-library) and even earlier as [`array_ref`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html).

Those bold parts are *critical* to one's understanding, so don't miss them or misread them! A `span` is NOT a C-array of structs, nor is it a struct of a C-array of type `T` plus the length of the array (this would be essentially what the `std::array` *container* is), NOR is it a C-array of structs of pointers to type `T` plus the length, but rather it is a **single** struct containing one single **pointer to type `T`**, and the **length**, which is the **number of elements (of type `T`) in the contiguous memory block that the pointer to type `T` points to!** In this way, the only overhead you've added by using a `span` are the variables to store the pointer and length, and any convenience accessor functions you use which the `span` provides.

This is UNLIKE a `std::array<>` because the `std::array<>` actually allocates memory for the entire contiguous block, and it is UNLIKE `std::vector<>` because a `std::vector` is basically just a `std::array` that also does *dynamic growing* (usually doubling in size) each time it fills up and you try to add something else to it. A `std::array` is fixed in size, and *a **`span`** doesn't even manage the memory of the block it points to, it just points to the block of memory, knows how long the block of memory is, knows what data type is in a C-array in the memory, and provides convenience accessor functions to work with the elements in that contiguous memory*.

### It *is* part of the C++ standard:

`std::span` is part of the C++ standard as of C++20. You can read its documentation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span. To see how to use Google's `absl::Span<T>(array, length)` in C++11 or later *today*, see below.

### Summary Descriptions, and Key References:

1. `std::span<T, Extent>` (`Extent` = "the number of elements in the sequence, or `std::dynamic_extent` if dynamic". A span just *points to* memory and makes it easy to access, but does NOT manage it!):
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span
3. `std::array<T, N>` (notice it has a *fixed* size `N`!):
4. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
5. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/
6. `std::vector<T>` (automatically dynamically grows in size as necessary):
7. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
8. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

### How Can I Use `span` in C++11 or later *today*?

Google has open-sourced their internal C++11 libraries in the form of their "Abseil" library. This library is intended to provide C++14 to C++20 and beyond features which work in C++11 and later, so that you can use tomorrow's features, today. They say:

> **Compatibility with the C++ Standard**

> Google has developed many abstractions that either match or closely match features incorporated into C++14, C++17, and beyond. Using the Abseil versions of these abstractions allows you to access these features now, even if your code is not yet ready for life in a post C++11 world.

### Here are some key resources and links:

1. Main site: https://abseil.io/
2. https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/
3. GitHub repository: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp
4. `span.h` header, and `absl::Span<T>(array, length)` template class: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/types/span.h#L153

### Other references:

1. [Struct with template variables in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448242/struct-with-template-variables-in-c/2448307#2448307)
2. [Wikipedia: C++ classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#:%7E:text=A%20structure%20is%20a%20class,reserved%20for%20data%20without%20functions.)
3. [default visibility of C++ class/struct members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247745/default-visibility-of-c-class-struct-members)

### Related:

1. [another one of my answers on templates and spans] [How to make span of spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449789/how-to-make-span-of-spans/67454463#67454463)

Comment: I would really not recommend using all of abseil to get a span class.

Comment: got it. The biggest advantage is light-weight.

Comment: @yushang, from a C++ developer's point-of-view, I think the biggest advantage isn't "light-weight", but is rather: "wraps around already-existing C arrays", so that no copying is necessary, and you now have a wrapper around a container which holds its size inside of it, unlike C arrays, which don't know nor carry around information about their own size. As an embedded developer, with more experience in C than in C++, myself, however, I'd generally prefer to just use raw C arrays anyway, over a span.

Comment: `void array_operator ( const size_t count_, char arr [ static count_ ] );` that is standard C.  In there one has full array info.  Plus `arr` must have min `count_`  elements.  Context is this discussion not "C is better" rant.

Comment: Also, this bothers me too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::span-is-not-zero-cost-because-of-th/1429284

Comment: It is not a wrapper to a C-style array; `std::array` is a wrapper to a C-style array. `std::span` is a *reference* to a contiguous sequence, such as a C-style array.

Comment: @JohnMcFarlane, I see what you're saying but you're just artificially limiting the word "wrapper" to mean "cannot contain just a pointer or reference, and length." That's unnecessarily narrow. The first thing I did was present a possible span implementation at the top of my answer, in code, and with comments, which agrees with what you said. Then, I called that struct container, known as a span, a "light-weight wrapper around a C-style array" because it points to a contiguous piece of memory and wraps it with accessor methods and the array's size. I call that a "light-weight wrapper."

Comment: @GabrielStaples `span` is certainly not a container. It does not own the pointee or control its lifetime. OTOH, it does owns a pointer and control that pointer's lifetime. So if `span` is a wrapper, then it's a wrapper around a pointer.

Comment: @JohnMcFarlane, agreed. A `span` is a wrapper around a pointer and a length variable (plus functions). That's what I mean by "light-weight".

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by Einpoklum is great but I had to dive deep into the comments section to understand one specific detail so this is meant as an extension to clarify that detail.

> First, when not to use it:
>
> Don't use it in code that could just take any pair of start & end
> iterators, like std::sort, std::find_if, std::copy and all of those
> super-generic templated functions. Don't use it if you have a standard
> library container (or a Boost container etc.) which you know is the
> right fit for your code. It's not intended to supplant any of them.

Any pair of start & end iterators **as opposed to start and end pointers of continuous storage.**

As someone who rarely gets into contact with the interior of iterators it escaped me during my reading of the answer that iterators could iterate over a linked list, which simple pointers(and a span) could not.

Comment: `span`s are constructible from contiguous iterators, which are not necessarily pointers. `vector::iterator` is contiguous, but not a pointer -- for example. The comment you quoted effectively boils down to "use the right tool for the job"; if you are writing an algorithm/utility over an arbitrary sequence, don't try to erase it into a `span` since this prevents any normal container from being used. However, if you want to have a container that represents non-owning contiguous data, `span` is likely the right call.

Comment: iterators could iterate over.... a linked-list, a red-black tree, a hashmap (all of which have implementations in the C++ Standard Library), and anything else including third-party exotic containers.

Comment: I agree with what you two wrote. It seems to be a rephrasing/repetition of the very fact that I tried summarizing/highlighting here.

Comment: This answer inspired me to expand mine somewhat. So, +1 for it, but I hope now the point you are making is obvious enough when reading my answer.

Comment: I think it is obvious now, but I can no longer proof-read, because now I know and it's a detail that is hard to unlearn so I wouldn't know if earlier me would repeat my oversight.

I'll leave it to others to decide if my answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A span is (or rather: has) a pointer to data not owned by that span. In effect you can do ranged operations on a span that affect someone else's data.

This means you can write things like an in-place quicksort:

```
void qs( span<T> data ) {
   split(data);
   qs( span{ data+0,sizeoffirst } );
   qs( span{ data+sizeoffirst,sizeofsecond } );
```

or any number of Lapack-style linear algebra functions by recursion or parallelism.

Comment: This is more of a comment.

Comment: After edit, is my about "when should I use it" clearer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34826238)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I have no idea what you're telling me about critique or clarification. I'm not doing either. Also: are you a C++ expert? I'm giving a usage scenario when it can be used, which answers the question.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen It also seems that you're the only one out of 3 reviewers that has a problem with this answer.

Comment: I don‘t have a problem with your answer, I just can‘t see any real new knowledge compared to the existing answers. In addition, it’s allowed to have different views, and if two other reviewers have different opinions then mine, that's fine and your answer stands. I struggle with answers that don’t bring new knowledge to light but only reinforce/repeat existing knowledge. You could make your answer unique by coding out examples of your mentioned recursion or parallelism, thus covering `span<T>` in that regard and isn‘t answered in any other answers.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I don't see my point about operating on (non-owned) *sub-arrays* covered anywhere. The important application area of linear algebra is not mentioned anywhere. For application scientists that is much much much more important than the fact that it's something light-weight. So the "when should I use one" is covered only in my answer: if you do linear algebra, or other operations (such as in-place sorting) where you want a non-owned sub-array. And that is unique to my answer.