# non-const in const vector

Tags: c++, stl

Why does range-for over `const vector<Thing>` yield `const Thing` ?

I thought  `fn_a` would compile fine :

```
#include <vector>

class Some {
    public:
      void not_const();
};


void fn_a ( const std::vector<Some> &vs) {
     for( Some &s : vs )
        s.not_const();

}

void fn_b (  std::vector<Some const> &vs) {
     for( Some &s : vs )
        s.not_const();
}
```

Errors ( omitting some others ):

```
a.cc:10:21: error: binding reference of type ‘Some&’ to ‘const Some’ discards qualifiers
a.cc:16:21: error: binding reference of type ‘Some&’ to ‘const Some’ discards qualifiers
```

Q: Is it possible to range-for over a const vector and get mutable elements ?

Comment: Make copies of the elements in the `for` statement and you can mutate them all you want. Why would you expect a `const vector` to allow you to mutate its contents?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does range-for over `const vector<Thing>` yield `const Thing` ?

A range-for loop uses an iterator to iterate through the vector. As such, it will call the vector's `begin()` method to get the iterator.  Calling `begin()` on a `const` vector yields a `const_iterator`, which returns a `const Thing&` when dereferenced.

> Is it possible to range-for over a const vector and get mutable elements ?

Not safely. You could `const_cast` away the `const` from the reference returned from dereferencing the `const_iterator`, but that is undefined behavior, especially in your `fn_b` example where the vector's items are themselves `const` to begin with.

If you want to work with mutable items, you need to work with a mutable vector.

Comment: yeah , but i am wondering about the rationale behind the philosphy of applying the  constness of container , to it's contents.  I wouldn't want a function to  modify the vector itself ( to avoid invalidation of other iterators ), but would want to modify the content ( first level, or somewhere deep down )  !

Comment: @VardhanVarma See [What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1896169)

Comment: @Justin what does that have to do with this issue?

Comment: @RemyLebeau vrdhn asked about modifying the content, but not the vector. In that case, a mutable span does exactly what they want

Comment: @Justin: AFAIK, you can't mutate items via a span of an immutable container. Look at Microsoft's [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) (since `std::span` is not available yet). Constructing a `gsl::span` from a `const` vector calls `gsl::span(const Container&)`, which only accepts `const T` as the span's `ElementType` and requires `Container::pointer` to be convertible to `const T*`. As such, the span's `operator[]`, `operator()`, and `at()` members will return `const T&`, the `data()` member will return `const T*`, and iterators will return `const T&`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, but the idea was to make a span over the non-const vector. Then the "vector parts" can't be mutated, but the contained elements are still mutable

Comment: @Justin: I know what the *idea* is, but based on the *implementation*, that is simply not possible with a span.  If the vector itself is `const`, the span will provide `const` access to the vector's items, even if the items are not themselves `const`.  Only a span of a non-`const` vector will allow non-`const` access to the vector items