# Is there anything similar to Python's indexing in c++?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, string, indexing

I am working on using parts of an array of chars in C++ and was trying to figure out the easiest way to do this. I know in Python you can simply do something like str[1:] which will give you the entire array except the first position and was wondering if C++ has any analogs to this or if not, what would be the easiest way to implement this.

Comment: You can get something similar, though much more verbose, with iterators and ranges. For example the range `std::next(std::begin(str), 1)` to `std::end(str)` would be `str` except for the first element.

Comment: In most languages that's expressed via named substring operations, names like `substr`, `left`, `mid`, `right`. The first from C++, the latter three from some Basic. For efficiency look up `std::string_view`.

Comment: You could use [`std::string::substr(1)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: in C++17 there is `std::strigng_view` (or boost `strigng_view` for older C++ versions). There is also something like `std::valarray` where `slice` functionality is very similar to pythons operator `[]`.

Comment: Note: this feature in Python is called slicing. Just thought I'd give you this terminology so you can do more effective searches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For right now you can try using as header-only [Boost.Range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) ([sliced](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html), etc.) library (+ there is a [chapter](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.range) about it at [theboostcpplibraries.com](https://theboostcpplibraries.com)).

Example from the library documentation:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    using namespace boost::assign;

    std::vector<int> input;
    input += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

    boost::copy(
        input | sliced(2, 5),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));

    return 0;
}
```

In future there will probably be something called `span<T>` in the standard (discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)).