# Proper unique_ptr declaration of 1 element allocated array

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I need to use an API as part of a project that includes a class called `ParamSet` with a method that is defined as the following:

```
void AddString(const std::string &, std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> v, int nValues);
```

The purpose of the method is to add an array of strings to the object to describe some parameter. For example a `ParamSet` object could require a "filename" parameter that points to an array of a `nValues` strings.

However, when I try and pass the method a `unique_ptr` to an array containing only 1 string, the code seg faults upon calling the destructor for the `ParamSet` object unless I define the `unique_ptr` in a specific way.

The following code causes a seg-fault upon calling `Clear()` or on `return`.

```
ParamSet badparam;
badparam.AddString("filename", unique_ptr<string[]> (new string("test")), 1);
badparam.Clear(); // <------ CAUSES SEG FAULT
```

However the following does not cause a seg fault.

```
ParamSet testparam;
std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> strings(new std::string[0]); // DOH, should be string[1]
strings[0] = std::string("test");
testparam.AddString("filename", std::move(strings), 1);
testparam.Clear(); // <------ NO SEG FAULT
```

I don't understand why creating the `unique_ptr` in the line calling `AddString` leads to a seg fault, but creating it outside of the call to does not.

Comment: Neither of those codes allocates a `std::string` array with one element.

Comment: You must use `new[]` if allocating for array form of unique_ptr

Comment: If the API just used `std::vector`, this would be way easier.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could do something like `make_unique<std::string[2]>("foo", "bar")`, but the standard has outlawed that

Comment: @o11c this seems like a good use case for [span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one), then the caller is not forced to use a particular container (be it `unique_ptr[]`, or `vector` etc.)

Comment: @M.M perhaps, though that would require `AddString()` to make a copy of whatever data is passed in, instead of take owrnship of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array specialization of `std::unique_ptr` requires the array to be allocated with `new[]`, as it uses `delete[]` by default to free the array.

In your first example, you are allocating a single `std::string` object with `new`, not a 1-element array with `new[]`.

In your second example, you are allocating a 0-element `std::string` array, but you need a 1-element array instead.

Try this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> strings(new std::string[1]); // <-- NOT 0!
// Or, if you are using C++14:
// auto strings = std::make_unique<string[]>(1);
strings[0] = "test";
testparam.AddString("filename", std::move(strings), 1);
```

Alternatively:

```
testparam.AddString("filename", std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>(new std::string[1]{"test"}), 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This syntax is exactly what I was searching for. I need C++11 for now so I'd need to write my own make_unique, but that's not so bad. The string[0] is my facepalm moment for the day...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use non-array `new` to allocate memory managed by `unique_ptr<T[]>` which will then go on to use array `delete[]`, causing undefined behaviour.

The syntax could be:

```
badparam.AddString("filename", std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>(new std::string[1]{"test"}), 1);
```