# In C++ is it possible to disambiguate between an array ref and a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading

I have this code:

```
template <typename T, ::std::size_t size>
using ary_t = T[size];

template <typename T, ::std::size_t size>
constexpr int call_me(ary_t<T const, size> &a)
{
    int total = 10;
    for (::std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr int call_me(T const *a)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}

#if 0
int t1()
{
    return call_me("a test");
}
#endif

int t2()
{
    char const * const s = "a test";
    return call_me(s);
}
```

and it works, but when remove the `#if 0` section around `t1` it fails to compile because of an ambiguity in which template to use. Is there any way to force the array version of `call_me` to be used preferentially?

I've tried a number of different tricks to make this work. I've tried adding `, int...` to the template argument list for the pointer version. I've tried removing the `const`. I've tried both. I've even tried making the pointer version into a C-style varargs function (aka `int call_me(T const *a, ...)`). Nothing seems to work.

I'd be happy with an answer that requires what is currently believed will make it into C++2a.

Comment: Yes! as I hypothesized. Thats not an array. You can't just T[size], that's a pointer in disguise. You have to T(&)[size]. Aside from your error, T(&)[size] is still ambiguous with T*. Cpp is strange. Similar to how 0 and nullptr is ambiguous where function accepts int or pointer.

Comment: @user13947194 - Oh, interesting. C++ declarations are very confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept to add a level of indirection, you can add an unused parameter to give the precedence to the array version.

I mean

```
template <typename T, std::size_t size>
constexpr int call_me_helper (ary_t<T, size> &a, int)
{
    int total = 10;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr int call_me_helper (T const * a, long)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr int call_me (T const & a)
 { return call_me_helper(a, 0); }
```

Comment: This is also an interesting answer, and it's also a completely C++11 answer, which is nice. I didn't mind using a newer version, but it's nice to keep ones code working for older compilers. It has no more indirection than the top rated answer. I would probably change the wrapper function to take a `&&` and use `::std::forward`. I should test that to make sure it'd work.

Comment: Well, OK, not C++11 because of the `constexpr`, but yes.

Comment: @Omnifarious - Exactly: it's a C++14 solution and, removing `constexpr`, also C++11; if you use `T const (&a)[size]` instead of `ary_t<T, size> &a` become also C++98. About perfect forwarding... yes, in a more complex example make sense; but, in this case, you don't use move semantics inside the `call_me_helper()` functions so, IMHO, a classic `T const &` is adequate.

Comment: Oh man! This is a super duper idea. Like, there is no such thing as an rvalue array, so logically all arrays passed to a function will be an lvalue. Note that {...} is a std::initializer_list<T> expression.

Comment: PS. This works for template functions and not template class template functions. The compiler, (gcc I use), still complains ambiguous overload.

Answer (score 8):

There's an easy workaround:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int call_me(T&& arg) {
    if constexpr(std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
        return call_me_pointer(arg);
    } else {
        return call_me_array(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I wish I'd though of it! :-) Though, wouldn't you want some `::std::forward`s in there?

Comment: This works, but I think you're adding more baroqueness to OP's already-baroque construct.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you achieve the same effect by using a **`span`**:

[What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)

You just replace the array reference with a fixed-size span:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <gsl/span>

template <typename T, std::size_t size>
constexpr int call_me(gsl::span<T const, size> a)
{
    int total = 10;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

And there's [no ambiguity](https://godbolt.org/z/dGhpxZ). What's even nicer is that now you can use standard-library algorithms on containers:

```
#include <numeric>

template <typename T, std::size_t size>
constexpr int call_me(gsl::span<T const, size> a)
{
    return std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 10);
}
```

Comment: That looks like the right answer. How does `gsl::span` achieve this magic?!

Comment: Double checking, it looks like there's no ambiguity because both call the pointer version now. :-(

Comment: @Omnifarious: Oh :-( ... well I still recommend using a span instead of an array ref.