# C++ add constant to slice of vector

Tags: c++, vector, addition

I know with `transform` I can add a constant to some vector like so:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a(3, 2);
std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), std::bind2nd( std::plus<double>(), 1 ) );
```

I was wondering how I could modify `transform` to add a constant to some slice `[index:end]` of the vector, e.g. the last two elements.

I can do it with a loop e.g.:

```cpp
for (int i=1; i < a.size(); i++) {
    a.at(i) += 1;
}
```

but maybe there's a better option

Comment: I tried that also, but oddly enough that yields `3 3 2` instead of `2 3 3`

Comment: Sorry, you'd need to add to both the begin iterators.

Comment: How do you think your for loop is not optimal, ie. in what way do you want to make it better? Easier to understand for you later? Easier to understand for future developer reading your code? Just less code? More efficient after compiler optimizations?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not very familiar with C++ and I read one should use the `<vector>` library... not sure if that then includes using `transform` as well @hyde

Comment: @eok It doesn't, the point of the std algorithms is that they're generic. They can use iterators of many different list types including but not limited to `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::array` etc...

Comment: `bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the last `N` elements? Use a reverse iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a(3, 2);
  std::transform(a.rbegin(), std::next(a.rbegin(), 2), a.rbegin(),
                 [](auto n) { return n + 1; });

  for (auto n : a) {
    std::cout << n << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

(Using `std::next()` instead of just `a.rbegin() + 2` makes it easier if you for some reason need to change `a` to a container type that doesn't have random iterators.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason algorithms take iterators, not containers, is exactly for cases like this.

The general method to adapt a Python style slice is to add `+ve` values to `begin` and `-ve` to `end`. Assuming there are at least two elements, incrementing last two elements would be

```
auto start = a.end() - 2;
auto finish = a.end();
std::transform( start, finish , start, std::bind2nd( std::plus<double>(), 1 ) );
```

Comment: `bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

The same code after a small refactor:

```
std::vector< int > a(3, 2);

auto start = a.begin();
auto end   = a.end();
auto func  = [](auto val) {
    return val + 1;
};

std::transform(start, end, start, func);
```

Now by modifying the values of `start` and `end`, only the slice can be modified.

For this [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) can be used:

```
std::advance(start, 1);
std::advance(end, -1);
```

In the above code:

- `start` is 1 element after the beginning (2nd element - element with index of 1).
- `end` is 1 element from the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a span (`std::span` in C++20, `gsl::span` earlier) to represent your slice. If you don't know about spans, have a look at:

[What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)

So if you write,

```
// ... vector a gets defined
auto slice = std::span(a).subspan(some_index);
```

The slice now behaves just like any standard library container. Specifically, you could write:

```
std::transform(slice.begin(), slice.end(), slice.begin(), [](auto v) { return v + 1; });
```

Comment: With deduction guides, I think `make... ` functions are not needed anymore.