# Best way to trim a vector from custom values

Tags: c++

is there a smarter/nicer way to trim a vector given a value I want to erase, something similar to what trim does for strings, e.g. from

```
0 0 0 1 2 3 56 0 2 4 0 0
```

to

```
1 2 3 56 0 2 4
```

I cannot find a trim-like function, is find/erase the best option?

Comment: find_if/erase is the idiomatic way

Comment: provide a code sample of what you tried... but using stl algorithms is in most ways preferable and a nice way

Comment: btw... are you trying to delete duplicates or leading/trailing zeros??

Comment: My code looks like lisyarus and Tony below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we are working with a

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

We want to trim zeros, so

```
auto const is_not_zero = [](int i){ return i != 0; };
```

To find the first non-zero element and delete everything before it,

```
auto const first_non_zero = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_not_zero);
v.erase(b.begin(), first_non_zero);
```

To find the last non-zero, do the same with reverse iterators:

```
auto const last_non_zero = std::find_if(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), is_not_zero);
v.erase(last_non_zero.base(), v.end());
```

(`std::reverse_iterator::base` returns the underlying ordinary iterator from a reverse one).

Comment: `last_non_zero` is not best name since it points to zero or end.

Comment: @MarekR Fair point, thank you. I've changed the code slightly so that the naming looks better.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, I was wondering why there is no trim-like function provided by algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, it's best to just *not* do anything with the vector and simply work with an iterator pair for the relevant range of elements. You could also use a [span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one):

```
#include <gsl/span>

// ...

auto non_zeros = gsl::span(nonzeros_start_iter, nonzeros_end_iter);
```

and you can use this span like any standard library container. In C++20 you can switch `gsl::span` to `std::span`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a full implementation on any type with given parameter.

```
template<typename T>
void TrimVector(vector<T>& vec, const T& _t)
{
    auto end_index = find_if(vec.crbegin(), vec.crend(), [_t](const T& t) { return t != _t; } ).base();
    vec.erase(end_index, vec.cend());
    auto start_index = find_if(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [_t](const T& t) { return t != _t; } );
    vec.erase(vec.cbegin(), start_index);
}
```

to use it,

```
//TrimVector<int>(MyVec, 0);
//changed as suggested below,
TrimVector(MyVec,0);
```

TEST:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> myVec = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 56, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0 };

    TrimVector(myVec, 0);

    cout << "myVec:" << endl;
    for (auto it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it)
        cout << "\t" << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, there's no need to explicitly specify template parameter when using `TrimVector`. It's possible to write `TrimVector(myVec, 0)` and the compiler will deduce the parameter.

Comment: The function template parameter deduction is nothing new. It's been there since 1998. Unless, you're taking about the 'pre-standard' version of C++ when it was something like a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find out the first non-zero element index from the beginning as well as from the end, and then slice the vector using those indexes.

Here is the example :

```
vector<int> vec = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 56, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0};
    
// find begining index for non-zero element:
auto  beg_index = find_if_not(begin(vec), end(vec),[](int a){return a == 0;});
    
// find first non-zero element from the end :
auto end_index = find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](int a){return a != 0;});
    
//slice the vector using found begining and end indexes :
    
vec = { beg_index, end_index.base()};
```

This will trip vector from both the ends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).