# Vectors passed in as construction arguments

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

If I have a class similar to this:

```
namespace Matrix {
  class Matrix; 
  class Vector {
   public:
    //i want to create a vector the same size as contents with the same values
    Vector(const std::vector<ValueType>& contents);
   private:
   std::vector<ValueType> contents;
}
```

When contents is passed in through the constructor, is it automatically copied to the vector called contents I defined within the class? Or is there something I have to do in the constructor definition to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not get automatic copying just by virtue of your constructor having an argument. You could write:

```
Vector(const std::vector<ValueType>& contents_) : contents{contents_} { };
```

which would do the copying. However, this whole approach is not a good idea, for two reasons:

1. If you pass an rvalue to the constructor (e.g. a temporary vector you obtained from some function), a `const &` would make an extra copy.
2. Why only be willing to initialize your data from an std::vector? You should be willing to accept at least a [std::span](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077), or perhaps template over a container or a pair of iterators.
3. Actually, I would consider templating your entire inner vector class on the underlying container.

Comment: Its an assignment where I'm meant to define a bunch of already declared constructors and operators to create a matrix and vector class. I dont think I can change the constructor declaration