# How to represent boost array as a pointer of a type?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I'm using a boost array as a buffer and wanted to pass it on as an argument to a function. The way I would like to pass it is so that the size is determined as another argument so that I can pass over buffers of varying sizes. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
void DataTransform(boost::array<char, 1024> data) {
    //do something
}
```

With a normal array I could have just used:

```
void DataTransform(char* data, uint_16 size) {
    //do something
}
```

How would I go about unwrapping the boost array to represent it as a pointer?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a plain array like `char arr[SOME_SIZE];` then `arr` will *decay* to ***a pointer to its first element***. That is, `arr` will decay to `&arr[0]`.

Taking the address of an element of a `boost::array` (or, for that matter, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as well as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) is valid as well and gives the same result.

So to get a pointer to the first element of the `boost::array` you simply do e.g. `&data[0]`.

---

But if you don't want to deal with pointers, there's another way to handle your problem: Templates.

You can use a *value* template argument for the size of the `boost::array`, as in

```
template<size_t N>
void DataTransform(boost::array<char, N>& data) { ... }
```

and then you can pass a `boost::array` with `char` elements of any size to the function. The size will simply be deduced by the compiler:

```
boost::array<char, 512> data1;
boost::array<char, 1024> data2;
...
DataTransform(data1);
DataTransform(data2);
```

Answer (score 4):

`boost::array` has a `data()` [method](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/array.html#idm46563494182448-bb) that returns a pointer to the start of the array, and a `size()` [method](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/array.html#idm46563494209840-bb) that returns the number of elements in the array:

```
DataTransform(some_array.data(), some_array.size())
```

Another option is to rework your DataTransform method to work on iterators:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
DataTransform(T begin, U end) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        // do something with *begin
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like so:

```
DataTransform(std::begin(some_array), std::end(some_array))
DataTransform(some_c_array, some_c_array + some_c_array_size)
DataTransform(std::begin(some_list), std::end(some_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

> With a normal array I could have just used:
>
> ```
> void DataTransform(char* data, uint_16 size) {
>     //do something
> }
> ```

You could do that also with a `boost::array` but it would be a step backwards. There are good reasons, why containers manage theirs size and you dont have to do the bookkeeping.

If you want this

```
void DataTransform(boost::array<char, 1024> data) {
    //do something
}
```

to accept `boost::array`s of different size, I would suggest to parametrize the function on the size by making it a template:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

template <boost::array<char,1>::size_type size>
void DataTransform(boost::array<char, size> data) {
    //do something
}

int main(void)
{
    boost::array<char,10> x;
    boost::array<char,20> y;
    DataTransform(x);
    DataTransform(y);
```

}

PS: I am not that happy with `boost::array<char,1>::size_type` either and will open up a new question on that...

Answer (score 1):

You can using c++ 20 [`std::span<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) which is a very lightweight abstraction of a contiguous sequence of values of type T somewhere in memory.

see [What is a “span” and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)
.

This container is intend to solve your problem and your function interface can be declare in a very clear way:

```
void DataTransform(std::span<char> data) {
    //do something
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

You can just do this:

```
boost::array<char, 512>  d1;
boost::array<char, 1024> d2;
std::array<char, 512>    d3;
std::vector<char>        d4(512);
char                     d5[512];

DataTransform(d1);
DataTransform(d2);
DataTransform(d3);
DataTransform(d4);
DataTransform(d5); 
// Pass same buffer of varying size
DataTransform({d5, 256});
```

See online [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/42cB5I) example.