# Idiomatic way to get size_type from std::array or the like

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size-type

Triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604516/how-to-represent-boost-array-as-a-pointer-of-a-type/57604718#57604718), I came up with code along the line of (it was `boost::array` in my answer, but the same applies for `std::array`):

```
template <std::array<char,1>::size_type size>
void DataTransform(std::array<char, size> data) {

}
```

And I am not happy at all with `<std::array<char,1>::size_type`. I have to instantiate with a certain size, to know the `size_type`. For `std::array` I could have used `size_t`, but then what about the general case? What if `size_type` is not `size_t`? Or even more general (ie not for `std::array`) what if `size_type` is different for different sizes (silly but possible)?

I know this question is rather academic and there are many ways to avoid this "problem" completely (eg I could have passed iterators). Anyhow, I wonder...

**What is a clean way to determine the `size_type` for templates that need a `size` (of type `size_type`) to be instantiated?**

More generally, the question could be formulated as: How can I get my hands on a templates typedef that may depend on a template parameter before actually instantiating the template.

Comment: `std::array<T,N>::size_type` doesn't denote the type of `N`, that's always `std::size_t`

Comment: @Caleth yes I know, but I need to pick some `N` to be able to get `std::array<T,N>::size_type` and thats what I want to avoid. In general `some_template<N>::some_typedef` may depend on the value of `N` (it really would be silly if this would be the case for `std::array::size_type` but in general you never know..)

Comment: Even in the general case, the *type* of `N` doesn't depend on any part of the *instantiation* of `some_template<N>`, because it's part of the *declaration* of `some_template`

Comment: @Caleth maybe the question is based on a misunderstanding that the purpose of  `std::array::size_type` would be to get the `size_type` of a `std::array` when actually that is never needed. Maybe `array::size_type` is rather meant to be used when you have a instantiated container of unknown type ...

Comment: @Caleth ah ok now I get what you are trying to say. Uff, seems like I was really overthinking the problem. Nevertheless the answers show ways that can be useful in a more general scenario

Comment: @Caleth if you post this as an answer I would have to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the specific type the template uses.

`std::array<T,N>::size_type` doesn't denote the type of `N`, [that's always `std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) .

```
template <class T, size_t N> struct array
```

Even in the general case, the type of `N` doesn't depend on any part of the instantiation of `some_template<N>`, because it's part of the declaration of `some_template`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a C++11 solution that takes the array undeduced, then extracts the involved types and size in defaulted template arguments and finally does an `enable_if` to check if we were indeed given a `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template<
    class TArray,
    class TSize = typename TArray::size_type,
    class TValue = typename TArray::value_type,
    TSize size = std::tuple_size<TArray>::value>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::array<TValue, size>, TArray>::value>::type
DataTransform(TArray data)
{
    // Enjoy!
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KMziYq

Doing all this via defaulted template arguments means that this is SFINAE-friendly (all the checks are done during substitution). But it's also quite a mouthful compared to the C++17 solution :)

I should mention though that `std::tuple_size` (which has basically the same problem as the original question) *does* flat out use `std::size_t`. That shouldn't really be a problem because `std::size_t` should be able to hold all relevant values and we still extract and provide the "correct" `TSize` above. But you can do all this without `std::tuple_size` by writing your own one that is given `TSize` and deduces only the size value:

```
template<class TValue, class TSize, class T>
struct MyTupleSize;

template<class TValue, class TSize, TSize size>
struct MyTupleSize<TValue, TSize, std::array<TValue, size>>
{
    static constexpr TSize value = size;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zlseRm

Comment: @StoryTeller If `std::array` didn't provide the typedefs then this would be indeed impossible, I do believe.

Answer (score 4):

A purely C++17 solution would be to side-step the issue:

```
template <auto size>
void DataTransform(std::array<char, size> data) {

}
```

Let the type of `size` be deduced. Then just apply `decltype(size)` inside the function template if you need to use the type somehow.

Comment: I am still stuck with C++11, though as this question was mainly out of curiosity, I'll happily accept a C++17 answer

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - I don't believe the required machinery exists pre-C++17. But I'll be excited if someone proves me wrong on this.

Comment: sorry due to some mistake in my line of thinking, uncovered by Caleth, I have to accept a different answer. I dont think it makes sense to reformulate the question, but I'll just accept the correct answer for the question as it stands and imho the other answers are still very valuable contributions