# Why does std::basic_string_view support only const pointers?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

According to the description in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

> The class template `basic_string_view` describes an object that can
>   refer to a constant contiguous sequence of `char`-like objects with
>   the first element of the sequence at position zero.

However, it could be useful to use that class template with non-const `char` pointers, for example to write to a null-terminated byte string using the standard algorithms. For example, imaging an hypotetical `std::editable_string_view` owning a `char*`, one could write something like

```
void filler(char *str, std::size_t len, char c) {
    std::editable_string_view sv(str, len);
    std::fill(sv.begin(), sv.end(), c);
}
```

Are there reasons for `std::basic_string_view` to support only const pointers?

Comment: You might want to take a look at all the debate over `std::span` considering that's what this is, but not string-specific.

Comment: If you are using `cstring`s, why not use `memset`? I mean, you're talking about doing C operations in C++... use `std::string`

Comment: Hint: The answer is in the name.  *view*ing something shouldn't change it (unless we are talking about my cat in a box ;-) )

Comment: Why not use `std::fill(str, str + len, c);` What't the advantage of string view here (if it were mutable)?

Comment: string view is not used for modifying strings. You can use it on none const strings.

Comment: @chris very interesting the `std::span` solution. Since I can't use C++20 yet, are there alternatives in Boost, as far as you know?

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani See [What is a “span” and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/580083).

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani, Not that I know of, although there should be a number of light implementations on GitHub. However, it's not a drop-in replacement for `std::string` like `std::string_view` is. The reason I bring it up is that much of the discussion regarding whether `std::span` should be mutable applies to `std::string_view`'s design and you'll be sure to find points you haven't considered by researching those blog posts, talks, and papers.

Comment: i think i get what you want. yeah it seems useful on some ways. but `std::string_view` is for viewing only. if you want to modify a substring that also modifies the source-string, it should not be string_view. it's should be a different class. you can search from a third party library or you create your own.