# Is it possible to splice buffers in C++ with zero copy?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two buffers:

```
uint8_t* buf1[100];
uint8_t* buf2[10];
uint8_t* buf3[90];
```

Where `buf1` is full of data and I need to pass 10 bytes of this data to `buf2` and the rest to `buf3`. Is there a way to do this without copying?

If not, is there a high level library (like `std::vector`) in which splicing is possible without copying?

Comment: [std::list::splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)

Comment: Those are not buffers with data. They are arrays of pointers that aren't initialized..

Comment: @doug ok but in the case they were, is it possible?

Comment: What does it mean to "pass 10 bytes of data" to an array of uint8_t's ?   Assuming it doesn't mean copying, perhaps what you want is something like `uint8_t* buf1[100]; uint8_t * buf2 = &buf1[0]; uint8_t * buf3 = &buf[10];`. ?

Comment: sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  The three buffers are distinct objects with different addresses.  Therefore, some form of copying is necessary.

You can use a [`span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```
span<uint8_t*, 10> buf2(buf1, 10);
span<uint8_t*, 90> buf3(buf1 + 10, 90);
```

`span` is not in the standard library as of C++17, but it is available in the GSL.  See [What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819).