# c++ creating subvector operating on same data

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Hello I have a vector:

```c
vector<int> myCuteVector {1,2,3,4};
```

Now I would like to create a subvector in such a way, that it would contain 2 first elements from myCuteVector in such a way that after modifying subvectors elements, elements of myCuteVector would change too.

Pseudo code:

```c
vector<int> myCuteVector {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> myCuteSubVector = myCuteVector[0:2];
myCuteSubVector[0] = 5;
printf("%d", myCuteVector[0]) //would print also 5;
```

is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).  That would look like:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myCuteVector {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> myCuteSubVector{myCuteVector.begin(), myCuteVector.begin() + 2};
    myCuteSubVector[0].get() = 5; // use get() to get a reference
    printf("%d", myCuteVector[0]); //will print 5;
}
```

Or you could just use iterators directly like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myCuteVector {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> myCuteSubVector{myCuteVector.begin(), myCuteVector.begin() + 1};
    // it is important to note that in the constructor above we are building a list of
    // iterators, not using the range constructor like the first example
    *myCuteSubVector[0] = 5; // use * to get a reference
    printf("%d", myCuteVector[0]); //will print 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D I wonder if I will be able to pull out the size of the subvectors without additional variables in these methods. Is it possible?

Comment: @JakubBalicki Not exactly sure what you mean but `myCuteSubVector.size()` will give you the size of the sub vector.

Comment: @JakubBalicki Really though if you are implementing sorting algorithms you don't want to do any of this.  What you want is either to use iterator ranges (basically pointers) or pass the main vector by reference, and then pass the start and end indices of the sub vector.  Doing this is going to add a bunch of memory allocations and extra data which will hamper performance.

Comment: in the second method it still prints the size of 4. In the first method I get an error "incomplete type is not allowed" in the  myCuteSubVector[0].get() = 5; line

Comment: @JakubBalicki [Works just fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/331608323206f502)

Comment: Ok I was missing one lib, sorry for silly question :)

Comment: @JakubBalicki No problem, glad to help.

Comment: one more question, is my assumption correct that using span instead of iterator ranges in implementing sorting algorithms wouldn't hamper performance?

Comment: @JakubBalicki Using span would be a great replacement for iterator ranges.  Only reason I didn't suggest it is because C++20 hasn't officially come out yet so support is still limitied.  This code will work with a C++11 compliant compiler so it is "more portable" (more systems it can be used on without upgrading the system).  If you can use `span`, you should try it out.

Answer (score 5):

**Since C++20**, you can use `std::span`:

```
std::vector<int> myCuteVector {1,2,3,4};
std::span<int> myCuteSubVector(myCuteVector.begin(), 2);
myCuteSubVector[0] = 5;
std::cout << myCuteVector[0];  // prints out 5
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4lkxHLQO7lCq01eC.

Comment: But I just read here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one) that **It never allocates nor deallocates anything**. 
Learned something new, Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointers: -

```
vector<int> myCuteVector = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int*> myCuteSubVector;
for(int i = startPos; i < endPos; ++i)
    myCuteSubVector.emplace_back(&myCuteVector[i]);    //or you can use push_back()
```

Where startPos and endPos(excluding) specifies the indices from the original array which you want to change...

Then, to change value at position 'j'(which should be between [startPos, endPos)) with respect to the original array: -

```
*myCuteSubVector[j - startPos] = 123;
```

Of course, in your very specific case, you can simply write like this: -

```
vector<int> myCuteVector = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int*> myCuteSubVector = {&myCuteVector[0], &myCuteVector[1]};
*myCuteSubVector[0] = 5;
```

Not sure though why you would want to do this...

Comment: I'm trying to implement merge and quick sort in cpp in bunch of different ways. So now I'm messing around with vectors :D Thanks for the idea ^^