# for(auto) loop in print function is throwing an error, why?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, c++14

The `for` loop in `main` compiles fine but in the print function it doesn't, with the diagnostic

```
for(auto i:x) cout<<i<<" ";        

  -----------^std::end  
'end' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::end'?
```

being issued. Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
void print(int x[],int n)
{
   for(auto i:x) std::cout<<i<<" ";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    for(auto i:arr)
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    print(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget namespace std

Comment: When declared as a function argument, `int x[]` is really `int* x`. That is, `x` is a pointer and can't be used with range-for loops. Either use `std::vector`, `std::array`, or make the function a template with the array size as template argument and pass the array by reference. Using `std::array` is probably the simplest.

Comment: The basic mistake is mixing C elements (in this case, `[]` arrays, but pointers are another "contestant") with C++. An unfortunate result of most students being taught C *first* instead of starting with idiomatic C++ right away. But a whooping +1 for the self-contained example code!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the array `arr` *decays* to a pointer when passed to the function `print`. The mechanism behind the range-based `for` loop is via the use of `std::begin` and `std::end`. That goes some way in explaining the compiler diagnostic: they don't work if applied to pointer types.

This pointer decay is the normal behavior when passing array parameters to functions, but is by no means universal. For example, `std::begin` and `std::end` obviate this with some template trickery (otherwise they'd be useless for array types), something which you can do too by writing

```
template<typename T>
void print(T&& x, int n)
{
   for(auto i:x) std::cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

The plain old datatype int[] has no `end-iterator`, if you pass it to a function. In this case you yust pass a pointer to the first item. In order to use a range based for loop you have to use a data container, which has a begin- and end-iterator, such as `std::vector`

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/45ejrfPYr) is your code in a more `C++` way.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
    
void print(const std::vector<int> &x) {
    for(auto i:x) {
       std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> arr {1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 5};
    for(auto i:arr) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    print(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@schorsch312's answer is correct, but the suggestion to have the `print()` function take an `std::vector` is not the "C++ way": Using `std::vector` instead of a plain array in your main program is just fine, but when writing a function - I would recommend not to take a type more specific than what you actually need to perform the function's work, and specifically not allocate memory on the heap with a new vector.

For the case of you having a C array in your program, @Bathsheba's suggestion of a `print()` is better in my opinion, in that it [will allow](https://godbolt.org/z/E8r5M9jaq) you to pass the array as-such, and thus iterate over it properly.

However - for pedagogical reasons, I would suggest you consider this version `print()`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void print(const int (&arr)[N]) {
    for(auto i : arr) {
       std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

which illustrates how `print()` can take an array reference. You need the template when you don't know the array size apriori. (and this [also works](https://godbolt.org/z/a78f7fWoW) of course.)

Alternatively, you could use the standard library algorithm, `std::for_each`, like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[] {1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 5};
    for(auto i:arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::for_each(
        std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
        [](auto i) { std::cout << i << ' '; }
    );
}
```

Note that when you use the ranged-for loop, what happens is basically the equivalent of the `for_each` invocation, or of a raw for loop over an iterator beginning at `std::begin(arr)` and ending at `std::end(arr)`.

Yet another alternative - which does not require concerning yourself with iterator pairs - is to have a `print()` function taking a `span` ([What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077)). Here it makes some sense since a plain C array can be referred to by a span: It has contiguous element storage and a specific length. If you were to be using C++20, your span-using print function would look like this:

```
#include <span> 

void print(const std::span<int> &sp) {
    for(auto i : sp) {
       std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

and again you don't have to specify the length in your main function. C++14 doesn't have spans in the standard library, but the C++ Guidelines Support Library (see [here](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) or [here](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/)) has it, as `gsl::span` - and it works in C++14.

---

Nitpicks:

- There is no need to `return 0` from `main()` - that happens automatically.
- Please use spaces between `#include` directives and the angle-brackets (i.e. `#include <foo>`, not `#include <foo>`.
- Please use spaces before and after `<<` operators.
- To print a space, you don't need a string; the single space character suffices, i.e. `std::cout << ' '` rather than `std::cout << " "`.

Comment: Why are you showcasing all kinds of workarounds for C arrays instead of `std::array` if you are opposed to memory allocation? And OP is probably going to use those constructs in greater contexts as well, and `std::vector` *is* the go-to container (premature optimization and all that jazz)...

Comment: @DevSolar: 1. Because the question is about passing an array to a function. 2. `std::vector` is the go-to container - but not as a parameter to a function. Anyway, I'll clarify that in the answer body.