# Is there a way to create std::vector<arma::mat> from arma::mat matrices without creating a copy of the matrices?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am new to `C++`. For a statistical method, I compute large matrices, e.g. `A` and `B` . They are `n x n` so for large sample sizes `n`, they become very large. If they are `double` and `n = 70k` , I think it might be on the order of `30GB`?
Because the number of matrices needed can vary, I implemented the algorithm to use a vector of matrices and iterate over it for some operations. E.g.

```
arma::mat A;
arma::mat B;
std::vector<arma::mat> matrices;
matrices = {A, B};
```

Is there a way to create this `std::vector` without copying the matrices?

I tried to check whether the memory is the same by doing this:

```
logger->info("Memory address for A: {}.", (void *)&A);
logger->info("Memory address for matrices.at(0): {}.", (void *)&matrices.at(0));
```

And it showed different addresses so I assume it is creating a copy but I am not sure.

I tried to use

```
std::vector<arma::mat> matrices;
matrices.push_back(A);
```

The memory addresses differed still. With

```
std::vector<arma::mat> matrices;
matrices.push_back(std::move(A));
```

the algorithm no longer worked because the matrices were empty.

Comment: If you want something that acts like a vector, but actually points to the data from a different container, then you might want to look into [`std::span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good suggestion. The answer below does not seem to depend on external libraries for the C++ version I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the logic: Let the `std::vector` allocate the memory and create the matrices. Then you work directly with the elements in the vector. For example:

```
std::vector<arma::mat> matrices;
matrices.resize(2);
arma::mat & A = matrices[0];
arma::mat & B = matrices[1];
// Initializing the values of A and B, and do stuff with them.
```

Note: It is important to note here that the references to `A` and `B` will become invalid if you add more elements afterwards to the vector, i.e. if the vector grows. But since these matrices are so large, you want to avoid this anyway at all costs.

If the container needs to grow, you might want to take a look at e.g. `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

First, apply for memory in advance.
Second, use advanced constructors:
`mat(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = false, strict = false)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).