# ERROR: begin was not declared in this scope for(auto x:a)

Tags: c++, c++17, std-pair

```
pair<long long, long long> getMinMax(long long a[], int n) {
    
    pair<long long,long long> p;
    p.first=a[0];   // min
    p.second=a[0];  //max
    
    for(auto x:a)
    // for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        // long long x=a[i];
        if(x<p.first)
            p.first=x;
        if(x>p.second)
            p.second=x;
    }
    return p;
}
```

WROTE THIS CODE

it shows error on for(auto x:a);

what is wrong with that , please explain;

Comment: Array function parameters are C++'s biggest lie. `long long a[]` looks like it declares an array, but it is actually silently transformed into a `long long * a` parameter. And a range based for loop can't work with just a pointer because there is no way to determine how long the range is from just a pointer. You need to either wrap the pointer and size in a span, or use the old fashion for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: A [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might help.

Comment: Maybe look into [`span`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1741542), see also https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-range or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates to pass an C stylish array by reference like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream> // for std::cout
#include <cstddef>  // for std::size_t

template<std::size_t N>
void foo(int (&arr)[N]) {
    for(auto x: arr) { 
      std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    foo(arr); // outputs: 1 2 3
}
```

(N is the array size)
Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a good solution, but only if the array size is known at compile time.