Constructing an std::span<> from an std::ranges::forward_range?
I have the following function:
template <forward_range R>
void Merge(R src1, R src2, ostream& out);

But that only works for two containers of the same type. I need to create a wrapper for it to merge, e.g. an std::vector<int> and an std::list<int>, so my idea is to use an std::span as follows:
template <forward_range R1, forward_range R2>
void MergeSomething(R1&& src1, R2&& src2, ostream& out) {
    
    using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<R1>;
    
    std::span<T> src_span_1(src1);
    std::span<T> src_span_2(src2);
    
    Merge(src_span_1, src_span_2, out);
}

This compiles and works fine with two std::vectors:
    vector<int> v1{1, 3, 5};
    vector<int> v2{2, 4, 6};

    cout << "Merging vectors:"sv << endl;
    MergeSomething(v1, v2, cout);

But it doesn't compile for an std::vector<int> and std::list<int>, "no matching constructor for initialization of std::span<int>" error:
    vector<int> v1{60, 70, 80, 90};
    list<int> int_list{65, 75, 85, 95};

    cout << "Merging vector and list:"sv << endl;
    MergeSomething(v1, int_list, cout);

Let alone for containers with different value types (e.g. int and double).
I tried changing the Merge and MergeSomething functions as follows, but there are multiple errors ("std::list does not provide a subscript operator" and "No matching constructor for initialization of std::span<int>")
template <forward_range R1, forward_range R2>
void Merge(R1 src1, R2 src2, ostream& out) {
 size_t i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < src1.size() && i2 < src2.size()) {
        if (std::less{}(src1[i1], src2[i2])) {
          .
          /*do the merge...*/
          .
        }
    }
}

template <forward_range R1, forward_range R2>
void MergeSomething(R1&& src1, R2&& src2, ostream& out) {
    std::span<std::ranges::range_value_t<R1>> s1(src1);
    std::span<std::ranges::range_value_t<R2>> s2(src2);
    
    Merge(src1, src2, out);
}


Since the documentation on ranges is kind of sparse for now, can anyone clarify how to do this properly? Thnx!

There no need to build the wheel yourself, you can just use ranges::merge which has similar concept std::mergeable.

You can't construct std::span from an arbitrary forward range. For a span you need a contiguous range, and not any forward range is contiguous.

@Evg, Thank you! That sorted out the construction problem, but now I realize that an std::list is not a contiguous_range... and neither is a std::vector or a std::deque<>. This clarified some of the issues with my code in the example, thanks! I guess, in this particular case it is best to use iterators rather than std::ranges and std::span.

Why not to use std::ranges::merge() that does accept two ranges of different types?

@Evg Or that, yes! I stumbled upon this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one, which made me think "hey, I can just use a pair of iterators, forget the spans and stuff". Using just std::ranges for my example code without using std::span would also work fine,  now that I think about it. I also know a bit more about adapters & pipelines now (after a few days), so can now make std::ranges::merge() do what I needed =)
